# .htaccess 301 redirect from /?p=blahblahblah

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to set up 301 redirects in the .htaccess file of a site that I converted to WordPress.

The old site had URLs that looked like the following

```
http://www.example.com/?p=about
http://www.example.com/?p=contact-us
```

The Rewrite rules I have tried are below, but none work.

```
Redirect 301 /?p=about /about/
Redirect 301 /?p=contact-us /contact-us/

Redirect 301 /?p=about http://www.example.com/about/
Redirect 301 /?p=contact-us http://www.example.com/contact-us/

Redirect 301 /\?p=about /about/
Redirect 301 /\?p=contact-us /contact-us/

Redirect 301 /\?p=about http://www.example.com/about/
Redirect 301 /\?p=contact-us http://www.example.com/contact-us/
```

It seems as if the WordPress rewrite rules are kicking in first, even though I have the 301 Redirect's above the WordPress redirect rules. The page that is displayed is the blog roll page which displays "Nothing Found" because I have no posts.

Is there a way I can make these redirects work?

Comment: Have you tried opening a private tab in your browser and seeing if the redirects work (or try a browser you've never visited the site before on)? A 301 redirect is permanent, which most browsers will cache until it's explicitly cleared out.

Comment: Just tried that. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are right : the redirect rules will not be taken into account if they are put after WordPress ones. This line :

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

will redirect everything, and le `[L]` at the end means that this is the last rule.

Here is would you should put in your `.htaccess` file :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# old site redirections
RewriteRule /?p=about /about/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule /?p=contact-us /contact-us/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```